# What solution exists to run installation of applications that have an installation wizard in windows

Tags: windows, automation

I am trying to automate the entire process of clicking next , next next .. etc which is needed to  install a application on windows. Is this possible ? How can it be achieved ?

I need a software that installs other software on its own, once it is given the installation file. 
In what scripting language is it possible to do this ?

If I were to develop such an application myself, where would I need to start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some allow for silent switches, in which case google the software used to create the installer and run it with particular switches from the command line.

If no such switches are offered then the only solution is software that allows automation of windows. [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com/) is great for this as it allows you to click buttons directly, not by automating the mouse, allowing the automation to happen in the background.